# Equally distribute a pandas Dataframe based on column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with unevenly distributed labels:

```
a      label
0        0
1        0
2        0
3        0
4        0
        ..
65693    7
65694    7
65695    7
65696    7
65697    7
```

"Rows" per label:

```
1: 7673
2: 28930
3: 615
4: 7619
5: 3888
6: 2853
7: 5312
0: 8808
```

Now I need another DataFrame where each class is represented exactly 615 (min of the labels) times so the DF will contain 8 x 615 rows.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for minimal counts:

```
n = df['labels'].value_counts().min()
df.groupby('labels').head(n)
```

Comment: Thank worked! Thank you. I missed the .head() method. :)